# Проблема с выравниванием блоков

Tags: html, css

Не могу выровнять блок по центру относительно других. Вот часть кода.
Или если вкратце: Есть один блок display:block, в нем 2 блока inline-block а 3 нужно прижать к правому краю родителя, но чтобы он находился вертикально по центру относительно других. Как это сделать?

Делаю здесь http://ravlex.pluton-host.ru/polar/cart.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.formdostavka input[type=radio] + .descdostavka:before {
  content: "\f07a";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #0e62bd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 13px 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.descdostavka {
  font-family: "MuseoSansCyrl-500";
  font-size: 15px;
}
.boxdost {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 630px;
}
.boxprice {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="descdostavka">
  <div class="boxdost">
    <span class="titledostavka">Доставка заказа стоимостью до 15000 руб.</span>
    <span class="descrdostavka">Стоимость доставки по Московской области, а так же доставки по Москве в пределах МКАД
          заказов до 15 тысяч рублей - уточняйте дополнительно у наших менеджеров.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxprice">
    <span>Стоимость: 0 руб.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Используйте flex

Comment: Flex поможет выровнять по вертикали, но прижать к правом краю тогда не получится.

Comment: Откуда вы взяли? justify-content: space-between;

Comment: Попробовал. Это не то...

Comment: Значит плохо пробовали.

Comment: Andrey Fedorov, я давал это свойство родителю, он растягивает блоки по ширине, это не совсем то, что нужно.

Comment: Посмотрите код в моем ответе. Строго говоря `justify-content: space-between;` даже лишнее, потому как установлено по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left,
.middle,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
.left {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 60px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.middle {
  flex: 10 1;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.right {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex: 1 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    Доставка заказа стоимостью до 15000 руб.
    <br>Стоимость доставки по Московской области - уточняйте дополнительно у наших менеджеров.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Стоимость: 0 руб.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Geyan Это пример. Я надеюсь у TC  голова на месте, он разберется что тут к чему и напишет себе правильный css.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, я смогу применить это. А бутстрап с флексом можно модружить с помощью медиазапросов, примерно на 700px меняем отображение с flex на block и всё.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.formdostavka input[type=radio] + .descdostavka:before {
  content: "\f07a";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #0e62bd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 13px 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.descdostavka {
  font-family: "MuseoSansCyrl-500";
  font-size: 15px;
  max-width 960px;
}
.boxdost {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.boxdost > span{
float: left;  
  max-width: 630px;
  min-width: 630px;
  display: block;
}
.boxprice {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 630px);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="descdostavka">
  <div class="boxdost">
    <span class="titledostavka">Доставка заказа стоимостью до 15000 руб.</span>
    <span class="descrdostavka">Стоимость доставки по Московской области, а так же доставки по Москве в пределах МКАД
          заказов до 15 тысяч рублей - уточняйте дополнительно у наших менеджеров.</span>
    <div class="boxprice">
    <span>Стоимость: 0 руб.</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxdost">
    <span class="titledostavka">Доставка заказа стоимостью до 15000 руб.</span>
    <span class="descrdostavka">Стоимость доставки по Московской области, а так же доставки по Москве в пределах МКАД
          заказов до 15 тысяч рублей - уточняйте дополнительно у наших менеджеров.</span>
    <div class="boxprice">
    <span>Стоимость: 0 руб.</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxdost">
    <span class="titledostavka">Доставка заказа стоимостью до 15000 руб.</span>
    <span class="descrdostavka">Стоимость доставки по Московской области, а так же доставки по Москве в пределах МКАД
          заказов до 15 тысяч рублей - уточняйте дополнительно у наших менеджеров.</span>
    <div class="boxprice">
    <span>Стоимость: 0 руб.</span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```